# Kafka JDBC transactional source config

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to get rows from two tables using kafka-connect.
I configured the `connect-file-source.properties` in this way

```
name=jdbc_source_postgres_foobar_01
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
#key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
#value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/store?user=postgres&password=root
table.whitelist=author,book
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
validate.non.null=false
topics=author,book
topic.prefix=
```

Involved tables are `author` and `book`, the latter has a foreign key refers to `author`.

Then I registered a listener to consume messages from "author" and "book" topics in order to insert them in another database.

```java
@KafkaListener(
    topics={"author","book"}, 
    groupId = "foo", 
    containerFactory = "fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
)
public void listenGroupFoo(@Payload PostgresTableRow message) {
    System.out.println("Received" + message);
    String tableName = message.tableName();
    HashMap<String, Object> params = message.params();
    
    insert(tableName, params);
}
```

This worked fine when involved tables have not constraints between each others, but in this case I get errors when messages from "book" topic are consumed before messages from "author".

For example, I insert in the source DB the author "George Orwell" with `id=23` and the book "1984" with `id=37` and `authorId=23`, two messages are pushed into Kafka, one in "author" topic and one in "book" topic.
If messages are consumed first from "book" topic and then from "author" topic, I get the error that cannot insert in my sink DB the book with id 37 because no such author exists with id 23.

So how can I solve this? There is a way to push multiple table into a single topic and grant the order?

Comment: Which source & target db engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a complex problem to solve in the CDC (Change Data Capture) world with Kafka in the middle.

You want to implement Transactionally Consistent, Ordered, Exactly-Once Replication from the Database to Kafka and from Kafka to another Database in such a way those referential integrity problems you're facing, i.e: due to race conditions, do not occur.

I recommend reading Robin Moffatt articles regarding CDC and Kafka Connect JDBC Connector as well as Shawn Robertson presentation on Kafka Summit 18 about this very same issue.

1. [No More Silos: How to Integrate Your Databases with Apache Kafka and CDC](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc/)
2. [Kafka Connect Deep Dive – JDBC Source Connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/)
3. [Transactionally Consistent, Ordered, Exactly-Once Replication from the Database to Kafka in the Cloud and Back—A Solution for Leveraging Kafka to Provide End-to-End ACID Transactions](https://kafka-summit.org/sessions/exactly-once-replication-database-kafka-cloud/)

Unfortunately, without an off-the-shelf end-to-end CDC solution, I guess you'll either need to be very creative or invest quite the effort to overcome that issue.